# How to get several records searching on the whole database

Tags: sql, oracle

My question is, is it possible to list all the columns from the whole database not just in specific tables based on 3 different criteria which ones are in an "OR" relationship. so for example I have database called "Bank" and I have 3 criterias "Criteria1; Criteria2; Criteria3" and if any of them is true so the relation between them should be OR and not AND than I will get back all the columns matching the criterias and the output put should provide "account_id" or "customer_id" from the same table.

How do I procced in this case?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you probably don't want to do it. Anyway, you could write a stored procedure that finds all tables that contain the columns you want:

```
  select distinct table_name from user_tab_cols utc
    where exists (select * from user_tab_cols where table_name = utc.table_name
      and column_name = 'ACCOUNT_ID')
      and exists (select * from user_tab_cols where table_name = utc.table_name
      and column_name = 'CUSTOMER_ID');
```

Given the tables you could run a query where you append table name and your criteria:

```
execute immediate 'select account_id, customer_id from agreement where '
  || your_criteria_here;
```

A bit messy, inefficient and treat this as pseudo-code. However, if you really want to do this for an ad-hoq query it should point you in the right direction!